# Dynamic arrays in gSOAP the C++ way, using STL vector instead of __ptr/__size?

Tags: c++, stl, gsoap

I am developing a web service using gSOAP 2.8.8.  I would like to send an unbounded sequence of a custom data type.  I can implement this by following [section 11.11 of gSOAP's User Guide](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soapdoc2.html#tth_sEc11.11) like so:

```
class ns__InnerType {
  std::string someStr;
  int someInt;
};
class VectorOfInnerTypes {
  ns__InnerType* __ptr;
  int __size;
};
void ns__myMethod(VectorOfInnerTypes in, ns__EmptyResponse out);
```

This works well.  However, since my program is in C++, I would like to take advantage of STL vectors.  From everything I've read it appears that gSOAP supports serializing vectors.  Here's what I believe should work:

```
#import "stlvector.h"
class VectorOfInnerTypes {
  std::vector<ns__InnerType> mylist;
};
```

soapcpp2 is happy to compile this, and I am able to pass a C++ vector when calling the stub's `myMethod`.  However, here's what goes over the network:

```
<s:Envelope ...>
  <s:Body s:EncodingStyle=...>
    <q1:myMethod xmlns:q1="urn:ns"/>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Compare this to the network traffic when I use the `__ptr`/`__size`:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope ...>
  <SOAP-ENV:Body ...>
    <ns:myMethod>
      <mylist xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="ns:InnerType[3]">
        <item>...</item>
        <item>...</item>
        <item>...</item>
      </mylist>
    </ns:myMethod>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

To get `std::vector` to work, I've tried various combinations of:

```
std::vector<ns__InnerType> mylist;
std::vector<ns__InnerType*> mylist;
std::vector<ns__InnerType>* mylist;
std::vector<ns__InnerType*>* mylist;
```

with the requisite `soap_new_std__vectorTemplate...` and `soap_new_ns__InnerType` when preparing data on the client, but there's no improvement.  It refuses to serialize correctly.

Both when it works (`__ptr`/`__size`) and when it doesn't (`std::vector`), the invocation of `myMethod` returns code 202, or HTTP Accepted.

How can I, and everyone who uses gSOAP in a C++ program, use STL vectors instead of the primitive `__ptr`/`__size` way?  Any help would be much appreciated.