# gsoap allocating mem for dynamic array of structures.

Tags: c, memory, malloc, gsoap

gSoap usefully creates stubs to help with memory management etc. One of these
commands is soap_malloc but there doesn't seem to be a corresponding soap_realloc.
Before I start to write my own push and pop methods I just want to ensure I'm not missing anything obvious.

```
//example.h generated with wsdl2h

struct ns1___Customer
{
    int   __sizeProduct;     
    ns1__Product *Product;        
    int  customerid;       
}

struct ns1__Product
{
    int  productid;
}
```

I am currently using soap_malloc and then realloc for dynamically growing the array.

```
//I could use soap_new_ns1__Product(&soap,XXX) and allocate mem for XXX
//number of ns1__Product structures but this is wasteful and doesn't solve 
//anything

struct ns1__Customter cust;
soap_default_ns1__Product(soap, &cust);

struct ns1__Product *prod_array = NULL;

//allocate mem for 1 product
prod_array = soap_new_ns1__Product(soap,1) ;

soap_default_ns1__Product(soap, &prod_array[0]);
prod_array[0].productid=111;

//Need to add product therefore need to realloc mem. 
//IS THIS THE BEST WAY IN gsoap?
prod_array = realloc( prod_array, 2 * sizeof(struct  ns1__Product)) ;
soap_default_ns1__Product(soap, &emp_array[1]);
prod_array[1].product=222;

//assigning array ptr to Customer
cust.Product=prod_array;
// Remember to adjust sizeProduct
cust.__sizeProduct=2;
```

This seems wrong and clumsy, does gsoap suggest a better way? I can't find a clear example in the documentation or by searching online.

Comment: What WSDL or .xsd schema did you use to generate that header? Adding the relevant bit(s) of that may prove helpful, as well as your `wsdl2h` and `soapcpp2` commands.

Answer (score 1):

> Before I start to write my own push and pop methods I just want to ensure I'm not missing anything obvious.

I suspect you're missing that `soap_malloc()` allocates memory *that is automatically freed* under at least some circumstances.  As such, using `realloc()` to resize the allocated memory is begging for trouble.  There's a fair chance that the reallocation as such will succeed, but you're likely at minimum to end up with a nasty mess when gSOAP's automatic freeing tries to kick in in `soap_end()`.

On the other hand, I don't think you're overlooking any reallocation function.  [The docs](https://www.genivia.com/doc/soapdoc2.html) indeed do not seem to describe any.  You can always implement your own reallocation wrapper that allocates fresh memory with `soap_malloc()`, copies the contents of the original space (whose size you'll need to know somehow), and releases the original space with `soap_dealloc()`.

The bottom line appears to be that `soap_malloc()` is not intended to be a general-purpose allocator, and it is not particularly well suited to your use case.  It's primary objective appears to be internal, to relieve library users of any need to manually free the temporary objects that the library allocates.  I take exposing it to library users for their direct use to be intended as a convenience.

If you want the ability to reallocate blocks, then I suggest you obtain them in the first place via regular `malloc()`.  You'll want to read the docs carefully if you're going to mix `malloc()`ed data with `soap_malloc()`ed data, but it is likely possible.  Alternatively, consider approaches that do not require reallocation, such as storing your data in a linked list instead of a dynamic array.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing there is indeed wrong. After using `soap_new_T()` (where `T` in your case is `ns1__Product`), the `soap` context now manages that memory by holding onto the `ns1__Product*` pointer internally. Later, when you call [`soap_destroy()`](https://www.genivia.com/doc/guide/html/group__group__context.html#gaf7d0176161e9def36981e24faa1913d9) to free all `soap_new_T()`-allocated objects managed by the `soap` context, the context will be trying to free a pointer that no longer points to valid memory since you called `realloc()`.

As John Bollinger [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52301321/5689220), there's no built-in way in gSOAP to do something similar to a `realloc`. You'd instead just need to do the reallocation manually, e.g.:

```
// allocate memory for 1 product (as you already do above)
prod_array = soap_new_ns1__Product(soap, 1);

// ... do some stuff, realize you need to "realloc" to add another product ...

// allocate a new array, managed by the soap context
struct ns1__Product* new_array = soap_new_ns1__Product(soap, 2);

// copy the old array into the new one (assuming old_size is however many elements are in prod_array)
for(std::size_t i = 0; i < old_size; ++i)
{
    new_array[i] = prod_array[i];
}

// tell the soap context to destroy the old array
soap_dealloc(soap, prod_array);
```

---

Aside:

It seems like it should be possible to use an `std::vector<ns1__Product>` rather than an array, which would solve your problem in an arguably better manner, but that question was already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12538625/dynamic-arrays-in-gsoap-the-c-way-using-stl-vector-instead-of-ptr-size) to no avail. Unfortunately I don't know the answer to that at this time.

Comment: Although I haven't used soap_malloc(), it seems naïve to expect SOAP to handle any allocation over which it doesn't have complete control. If you change the size or the address, SOAP has no way of knowing that. Just be generous from the start, since it will be freed before it goes out of scope, theoretically. Or create a realloc of your own that handles the freeing and reallocating BEFORE doing a soap_malloc for what goes out the door.